# 2 foreach loop, repeating results

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Basically iv getting a list or orders, then a list of items associated with that user.

This is my code

```
$collection_array = array();
        $collection_items_array = array();

        foreach($getCollections as $k => $collection){
            $collection_array['CustomerAccountID'] = $collection['collection_account_id'];
            $collection_array['TotalCount'] = $collection['totalCount'];

            // Get order items
            $get_order_items = $Collection->getItems($collection['collection_account_id']);

            foreach($get_order_items as $i => $items){

                $collection_items_array['OrderID'] = $items['order_id'];
                $collection_items_array['OrderItemID'] = $items['item_id'];
                $cia[] = $collection_items_array;
            }

            $collection_array['CollectionItems'] = $cia;
            $ca[] = $collection_array;
        }
```

but when i echo this out, its showing all the correct results for the results but then it shows the seconds results + the results...

Comment: Which variable/ array is showing result with old result?

Comment: Aren't you overwriting "$collection_array['CollectionItems']" with every outer loop iteration?

Comment: $collection_array is working great, showing correct results, its $collection_items_array which is repeating

Comment: Try separate foreach loop. I mean, do not put second foreach loop inside first loop. Example:  foreach($getCollections as $k => $collection){ ... } (close first loop) then again foreach($get_order_items as $i => $items){ ... }

Comment: $collection_items_array = array(); put this code inside second loop. before $collection_items_array['OrderID'] = $items['order_id'];
                $collection_items_array['OrderItemID'] = $items['item_id'];